# Successful ajax post to spring security doesn't redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-security

Folks, I have a problem where a successful ajax POST (200) request to j_spring_security_check doesn't redirect correctly to a success.jsp page - which is in the same directory as the login page. The login.jsp page just redisplays - and I can't figure out why (Please note, I'm fairly new to ajax).

Following is the content of my login.jsp page. Any help would be greatly received:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <%--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>--%>
    <title>Money Tracker - Logon</title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div>
        <header>
        </header>
        <section>
          <div id="dialog" title="Login">
            <form id="login">
                <label for="userName">User:</label>
                <input id="userName" type="text" name="userName">
                <br>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input id="password" type="password" name="password">
                <br>
                <label for="rememberMe">Remember me</label>
                <input id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" name="rememberMe"/>
                <br>
               <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<script>

function ajaxLogin(form) {
    var userName = form.userName.value;
    var password = form.password.value;
    var rememberMe = form.rememberMe.value;
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/server/j_spring_security_check",
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        data: { j_username: userName, j_password: password, _spring_security_remember_me: rememberMe },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("x-ajax-call", "true");
        },
        success: function (result, xhr) {
            alert("Request was success. Status is: " + xhr.status);
            if (result == "ok") {
                alert("Result was OK. Status is: " + xhr.status);
                window.location.href = "success.jsp";
            } else {
                alert("Result was not OK. Status is: " + xhr.status);
                location.href = "loginFailed.jsp";
            }

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("Error with request. Status is: " + xhr.status);
            location.href = "loginFailed.jsp"
        },
        complete: function(result) {
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    $("#login").submit(function () {
        ajaxLogin(this)
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ajax requests don't redirect the parent page. Instead of ajax request use normal form-submit

Comment: Hi coding_idiot, would I only need to submit the form on the login request? As I mentioned to Vinoth, this is a lightweight, stateless, REST based server only. So the client could be anything - I'd need a generic way of logging in.

Comment: have you tried googling [Rest Authentication](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rest+authentication&oq=rest+authentication&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.1870j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

@Ruaghain I have one suggestion for you. The intention of Ajax is not to submit the entire form, It's just send few requests to server and load the response within the same page. As I checked your code your intention is redirect the page on success/failure responses. Why don't you submit the form and redirect to the page whatever you need. Anyway you are using server side validation for validating the user. Hope I made you some sense..

Comment: Hi Vinoth. I have a REST based server only (no web pages of any kind) which I ultimately want to be able to access, and display data to a client - be it on a browser, or an android device etc. Would what you suggest still be applicable? My client side programming ability leaves a lot to be desired I'm afraid.

Comment: As i observed your response above, you are using web services to get your response. So you may not able to change any kind of code in your server (hopefully).